# Error mounting NTFS partition after hybrid shutdown with Windows 8

Tags: mount

I've got this error and I can't access my files located in a different partition when I'm using Ubuntu, but when I'm using Windows 8 my files are accessible. I'm using Ubuntu as my main OS. I tried shutting down Windows 8 properly but still nothing happened. Is there any way where this can be fixed?

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/kris/BackUp Files: 
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/kris/BackUp Files"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: 
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 8):

What @grimpitch says is absolutely correct.

Just adding that you can mount windows 8 drive in read-only mode as the error message suggests.
It can be useful if you only want to look at and copy files from the windows drive.

For it, first you have to create a directory as mount point:

```
sudo mkdir /media/*youruser*/newdisk
```

Later, mount the drive with:

```
sudo mount -t "ntfs" -ro "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/*youruser*/newdisk"
```

Change words with *, with your user name. /dev/sda4 could be also different, depending on the partition is the one where windows 8 is installed.

Note the args values are taken for your particular error message, **for other users take the error message, change `-o` by `-ro` and type appropriate user name**.

Also, note, with this method, you **cannot** edit, write or create new files in the windows drive.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows 8, a feature called hybrid shutdown is enabled by default to make it boot faster. This function is leaving the filesystem in a hibernated state, so it doesn't get closed properly at shutdown. The explanation is here:

[hybrid boot in windows 8](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152937-what-is-hybrid-boot-in-windows-8-and-how-does-it-work/)

The guide with instructions on how to disable it is here:

[How to enable or to disable Hybrid Boot](http://www.techulator.com/resources/5201-How-enable-or-disable-Hybrid-Boot-Windows.aspx)